# What is this part of the code

Tags: java, overriding, runnable

I have some code that demonstrates the use of threads by the use of the Runnable interface.
I started with code off a website somewhere, and modified it to my liking. It works, but I don't understand part of it.
I tried to strip the code down to the essence of what I am asking, but I may have taken too much out. The code I have in NetBeans works, so this is working code, unless I messed it up by taking the wrong thing out.
But let me ask my question, and see if it can be answered regardless:
The part I don't understand is this part:

```
public String toString()
       {
return "Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + countDown;
       }
```

For the longest time, this just looked to me like a member variable whose name is dynamically set at runtime equal to the name of the current thread. But I have also read in more than one place that you cannot dynamically name variables in Java, so I guess that isn't what I'm looking at.
Then, I realized that NetBeans wanted me to put @Override right before this code section, because something is being overridden. But I don't understand exactly what is being overridden. Am I overriding the constructor of some parent class? If so, what class?

Anyway, here is the code:

```
package countdown;

public class Counter implements Runnable
{
private int countDown = 5;
public String toString()
       {
return "Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + countDown;
       }


public void run()
    {
   while(true) {
  System.out.println(this);
  if(--countDown == 0)
                      {
return;
                      }
                }
    }
}
package countdown;

public class Main 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
  new Thread(new Counter(), "" + i).start();
    }

}
```

Comment: For clarity, as it is pertinent to this question: In Java, ALL classes will implicitly inherit from java.lang.Object. This is part of the language specification. So, as a lot of people have already mentioned, your IDE suggests @Override on toString() since it's one of the methods defined in the Object class. For more information on toString(), read the javadoc for java.lang.Object, http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29.

Answer (score 1):

Every class implements `toString( )` because it is defined by `Object`. However, the default implementation of `toString( )` is seldom sufficient.

For most important classes that you create, you will want to override `toString( )` and provide your own string representations. Fortunately, this is easy to do. The `toString( )` method has this general form:

```
String toString( )
```

The `toString()` method of an object gets invoked automatically, when an object reference is passed in the `System.out.println()` method.

---

`@Override` serves as documentation for the reader and a double check in the compiler. 
Use the `@Override` annotation to indicate that a method is overriding another in the base class.

For e.g

```
@Override
public String toString()
       {
return "Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + countDown;
       }
```

See : [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what's up there is that you are overriding the `Object.toString()` method, which always returns some string representation of the named class.  All it's doing is composing a string like

```
"Thread XXX: 5"
```

In Java, you can always override a parent classes (non-final) methods; the `@Override` tag is just helpful hinting for tools.  But it's not setting the *name* of anything: it creates a new, anonymous string, and returns its reference.

If you called standard `toString()` on `Thread`, you'd get a string like "<#Thread 2348564>" or something equally useful; now, for this class, you get useful information.

Comment: I know I'm nitpicking, but you can't override 'final' parent class methods.

Comment: That is true, but if otherwise not indicated every method is declared virtual. "final" is an exception for this.

Comment: Yeah; being an OO purist I see that as broken and always forget.